# Decoding GoogleApi BigQuery object - elixir

Tags: google-bigquery, elixir, decode

I try decode `%GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableDataList` object to the map. 
I found the documentation:

https://hexdocs.pm/google_api_big_query/GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableDataList.html#decode/2

How to use decode function? Maybe, you know better solution? My data to decode:

```
RADODATA: {:ok,
 %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableDataList{
   etag: "xyz",
   kind: "bigquery#magic",
   pageToken: nil,
   rows: [
     %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableRow{
       f: [
         %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "x"},
         %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "y"},
         %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "1234"},
         %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "4321"},
       ]
     },
     %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableRow{
       f: [
         %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "x"},
         %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "y"},
         %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "1234"},
         %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "4321"},
       ]
     },
     ...
     ]}
```

Comment: Better than what? What’s wrong with the official way to go? What output do you expect?

Comment: I expect map or json.

Answer (score 3):

I merged the raws with the schema

here is my code:

```
defmodule Google.BigQuery.Utils do
  @moduledoc false

  @empty [nil, %{}, []]

  def merge_rows_with_schema(nil, nil), do: nil
  def merge_rows_with_schema(%GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableSchema{} = _schema, nil), do: nil
  def merge_rows_with_schema(%GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableSchema{} = schema, rows) do
    rows |> struct_to_map |> Enum.map(&merge_rows_with_schema_(schema.fields, &1["f"]))
  end

  defp merge_rows_with_schema_(_schema, fields) when fields in @empty, do: nil
  defp merge_rows_with_schema_(schema, fields) do
    fields
    |> Stream.with_index
    |> Enum.reduce([], fn ({field, i}, acc) -> [merge_row(Enum.at(schema, i), field)] ++ acc end)
    |> Enum.into(%{})
  end

  def merge_row(schema_field, field) do
    converted_val = convert(schema_field.mode, schema_field.type, schema_field, field)
    {schema_field.name, converted_val}
  end
  def convert(_mode, _type, _schema, value)  when value in @empty, do: nil
  def convert("REPEATED", type, schema, field), do:
    field["v"] |> Enum.map(&convert(nil, type, schema, &1))
  def convert(_mode, "RECORD", schema, field), do:
    merge_rows_with_schema_(schema.fields, field["v"]["f"])
  def convert(_mode, _type, schema, field), do:
    convert_primtive(schema.type, field["v"])


  def convert_primtive(_type, value)  when value in @empty, do: nil
  def convert_primtive("STRING", value), do: value
  def convert_primtive("BOOLEAN", value), do: value == "true"
  def convert_primtive("FLOAT", value), do: String.to_float(value)
  def convert_primtive("INTEGER", value), do: String.to_integer(value)
  def convert_primtive("TIMESTAMP", value) do
    String.to_float(value) * 1000
    |> trunc
    |> DateTime.from_unix!(:millisecond)
    |> to_string
  end

  def struct_to_map(struct), do:
    struct |> Poison.encode!() |> Poison.decode!()


end
```

using it:

```
defmodule Google.BigQuery do
  alias Google.Connection  # import the make_conn()
  alias GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableDataInsertAllResponse
  alias GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.QueryResponse

  @timeout 40_000

  @doc """
  Runs a BigQuery SQL query synchronously and returns query results in map structure
  ## Example

      project = "bigquery-public-data"
      query_str = "SELECT * FROM `usa_names.usa_1910_2013` WHERE name = 'Yoshiro'"
      Google.BigQuery.query(project, query_str, "false")
      #=> [
        %{"state" => "CA","gender" => "M","year" => "1922","name" => "Yoshiro","number" => "5"}
      ]

  """
  @spec query(project, String.t, boolean()) :: map
  def query(project, query_string, use_legacy_sql? \\ true) do
    query_request = %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.QueryRequest{
      query: query_string,
      useLegacySql: use_legacy_sql?,
      timeoutMs: @timeout
    }
    GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Api.Jobs.bigquery_jobs_query(Connection.get(), project, [body: query_request])
    |> process_query_reponse()
  end


  defp process_query_reponse({:error, %Tesla.Env{body: body} }), do: {:error, body}
  defp process_query_reponse({:error, reason }), do: {:error, reason}
  defp process_query_reponse({:ok, %QueryResponse{rows: rows, schema: schema}}) do
    {:ok, Google.BigQuery.Utils.merge_rows_with_schema(schema, rows)}
  end

end
```

adding also my connection module:

```
defmodule Google.Connection do

  @doc """
  Create a tesla connection to make an API request if doesn't exist, and if exist, 
  it brings the last buffered connection.
  It ALREADY has a token server in Goth (google authentication) library
  """
  def get() do
    {:ok, token} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")
    GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Connection.new(token.token)
  end

end
```

tests:

```
defmodule Google.BigQuery.UtilsTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  alias Google.BigQuery.Utils, as: BigQueryUtils


  describe "merge_rows_with_schema" do

    test "data types" do
      schema =
        %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableSchema{
        fields: [
          %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
            description: nil,
            fields: [
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
                description: nil,
                fields: nil,
                mode: "NULLABLE",
                name: "c",
                type: "INTEGER"
              },
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
                description: nil,
                fields: nil,
                mode: "NULLABLE",
                name: "b",
                type: "INTEGER"
              }
            ],
            mode: "NULLABLE",
            name: "a",
            type: "RECORD"
          },
          %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
            description: nil,
            fields: [
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
                description: nil,
                fields: nil,
                mode: "NULLABLE",
                name: "age",
                type: "INTEGER"
              },
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
                description: nil,
                fields: nil,
                mode: "NULLABLE",
                name: "name",
                type: "STRING"
              }
            ],
            mode: "REPEATED",
            name: "det",
            type: "RECORD"
          },
          %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
            description: nil,
            fields: nil,
            mode: "NULLABLE",
            name: "upload_time",
            type: "TIMESTAMP"
          },
          %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
            description: nil,
            fields: nil,
            mode: "NULLABLE",
            name: "corr_id",
            type: "INTEGER"
          }
        ]
      }

      row =
        [
          %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableRow{
            f: [
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{
                v: %{"f" => [%{"v" => "3"}, %{"v" => "1"}]}
              },
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{
                v: [
                  %{"v" => %{"f" => [%{"v" => "23"}, %{"v" => "bob"}]}},
                  %{"v" => %{"f" => [%{"v" => "21"}, %{"v" => "jim"}]}}
                ]
              },
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "1.528028549735E9"},
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "1234"}
            ]
          }
        ]

      expected_row = [
        %{
          "a" => %{"b" => 1, "c" => 3},
          "corr_id" => 1234,
          "det" => [
            %{"age" => 23, "name" => "bob"},
            %{"age" => 21, "name" => "jim"}
          ],
          "upload_time" => "2018-06-03 12:22:29.735Z"
        }
      ]

      assert BigQueryUtils.merge_rows_with_schema(schema, row) == expected_row

    end



    test "array with primitive types" do
      row = [
          %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableRow{
            f: [
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: [%{"v" => "1"}, %{"v" => "2"}]},
              %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableCell{v: "22222"}
            ]
          }
      ]


      schema =
        %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableSchema{
          fields: [
            %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
              description: nil,
              fields: nil,
              mode: "REPEATED",
              name: "a",
              type: "INTEGER"
            },
            %GoogleApi.BigQuery.V2.Model.TableFieldSchema{
              description: nil,
              fields: nil,
              mode: "NULLABLE",
              name: "corr_id",
              type: "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }

      expected_row = [%{"a" => [1, 2], "corr_id" => 22222}]
      assert BigQueryUtils.merge_rows_with_schema(schema, row) == expected_row


    end

  end

  test "convert timestamp" do
    unix_timestamp = "1.528028549735E9"
    assert BigQueryUtils.convert_primtive("TIMESTAMP", unix_timestamp) == "2018-06-03 12:22:29.735Z"
  end
end
```